# Xorg configuration file on Debian Testing

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I cannot find the Xorg configuration file on my newly installed Debian on my tablet-pc, so I followed this tutorial http://wiki.debian.org/Xorg
and ran the command "Xorg -configure", to which I got the following error messages:

> (EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)
>
> (EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to load module/driver  vmwgfx
>
> (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
>
> (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
>
> FATAL: Module fbcon not found.
> Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration
> failed.

Dose anyone know what this means and how I should proceed? Why is there a warning about vmware, and what is this fbcon module?

Answer (score 1):

fbcon module is used for frame buffer.
I resolve this issue installing this package `xserver-xorg-video-fbdev`.

---

**Edit**

After some researches, I found that this error message simply means that fbcon module has been moved into the kernel in recent release. Xorg configurator cannot find this because this is no longer a module. You can use the `xorg.conf.new` as your xorg configuration file and it will run without any problem.

Comment: It looks like I already have that package installed though...at least that's what the package manager tells me when trying to install the package..."xserver-xorg-video-fbdev is already the newest version. xserver-xorg-video-fbdev set to manually installed."...

Comment: Answer modified with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of Debian don't by default create a xorg.conf. The new Xorg is largely self-configuring and doesn't need one.